# ResNET152 Validation loss is Nan and a TypeError

Tags: validation, keras, nan, nonetype, resnet

I am a new ML enthusiast and was playing with the [Aptos 2019](https://www.kaggle.com/c/aptos2019-blindness-detection) dataset in Kaggle. I was trying various notebooks there and finally got [this one](https://www.kaggle.com/rubensteendam/aptos-resnet-vs-inception) pretty well explained, build on ResNET 152.

I have configured it for `Google Colab` and while running it, I am having Validation Accuracy in 1 and Validation Loss in 0, and the program stops immediately after first epoch and show the error:
`TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable`.

Here is a screenshot of the error.

[image: image 1]

[EDIT 1] Well, I am now getting the same error, even when the Validation loss is not Nan.

[image: pic2]

Comment: "I have configured it for Google Colab and while running it" -> it could be due to one of you cells that is not executed or some of variables are mis-assigned. Could you please share us that file too?

Comment: Here is the code: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/14ffAbU-Jrhd_M7qfGn16nciPT2ofBJcf?usp=sharing

Comment: I have changed the `steps_per_epoch` to reduce the execution time.